# Passing queries between chaincodes with privacy enabled

Tags: go, blockchain, hyperledger

I have two chaincodes - let's call them A and B - and I am trying to get A to invoke a method on B, in a setup that has privacy enabled. An example of the sort of call I'm trying to make is shown below.

```
func (e *ChaincodeA) someFuncOnChaincodeA(stub *shim.ChaincodeStub, args []string) ([]byte, error) {

    //Do stuff

    newArgs := []string{"somevalue1","somevalue2"}

    msg, err := stub.InvokeChaincode(chaincodeBName,"someFuncOnChaincodeB",args)

    if err != nil{
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    return msg, err
}
```

However, whenever I try to run this, it gives me the following error messages before killing my chaincode:

> [72047168]Error chaincode-chaincode interactions not supported for
>   with privacy enabled.
>
> Sending ERROR Error starting Simple chaincode:
>   Error handling message:
>   [72047168-5f5a-4017-862a-1329660e2076]Chaincode handler FSM cannot
>   handle message (COMPLETED) with payload size (0) while in state: ready
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

Evidently privacy interferes with chaincode-chaincode communications. Is there any way around this, to enable communications while maintaining privacy? Or is it a best-practice to put absolutely everything into a single gigantic chaincode?

Additionally, why does privacy interfere with chaincode-chaincode communications? I don't understand exactly why this occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is a known issue with hyperledger, that is being worked on. As such there is no current workaround, but there will likely be one in the future when this issue is dealt with.

[Relevent Issue](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/issues/905)